# Return one newest instance of the mail, based on subject, from multiple subfolders

Tags: vba, sorting, outlook

I have a search for items, in subfolders of the Inbox, based on subject line.

I am trying to return the most recent mail and have been using the code:

```
Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
```

I also tried `CreationTime` and `SentOn` in between the brackets.

The search returns mails with the same subject line in the following order:

9/23/2016 9:31 AM
10/19/2016 12:57 PM
9/29/2016 10:54 AM

My code:

```
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant

Set oOLapp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olNs = oOLapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For step = 1 To MaxCount 
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    For Each Fldr in Fldr.Folders
        Set Items = Fldr.Items
        Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

            For Each olMail in Items 
                If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Text" & Cstr(step))
                    olMail.Display Then 
                    Set Msg = oOLapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                    .Attachments.Add olMail, olEmbeddeditem
                    Set Msg = Nothing
                End If 
            Next 
    Next 
Next
```

I want the one newest instance of the mail.

---

I also tried the code below where people seem to have the most success when trying to retrieve the most recent code.

I get

> Error404 "Array index out of bounds"

```
For step = 1 To MaxCount 
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    For i = Fldr.Folders.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Fldr = Fldr.Folders(i)
            For a = Fldr.Items.Count To 1 Step - 1
                Set olMail = Fldr.Items(a)
                //Search and attachment code. See previous code
            Next 
        Next 
    Next
```

---

**RESULT:**
My code pulls the mail in sequential order based on the folders it looks in. So the mail with the earliest time stamps went into a folder that appeared before the other mail so that is why my code kept pulling the earliest one instead of the latest one.

Comment: Please show your full code. Do you retrieve MAPIFolder.Items only once and cache it for all calls? Or keep calling MAPIFolder.Items every time?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have included my code in my post now.

Comment: What is your code that logs the items? Are you sure it logs the ReceivedTime property?

Comment: It doesn't log the ReceivedTime Property. My main goal is to attach the most recent email to a new composition but it doesn't always grab the newest version of the searched mail. I am only basing the time stamps based on the order the windows pop up and the order the emails get attached to the email. I have included the attachment code in my post.

Comment: Then how do you know the order is wrong? Can i be that the attachments are displayed in the wrong order?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified. So all 3 of the emails have the same subject line. When I only allow the program to attach the first instance, it only attaches the oldest email. When I allow it to attach two instances of the searched subject line, it attaches the oldest and then the newest one. But I only need newest instance of the email .

Comment: Again, do you log the value of the ReceivedTime property when you do that?

Comment: I just put in a debug code that records the ReceivedTime property and it matches exactly what was stated in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem running the following script in - all the messages are in the expected order - from older to newest. Did you mean to sort newest to oldest?

```
set folder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set items = folder.Items
items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
For Each msg in items
  Debug.Print msg.ReceivedTime & "  " & msg.Subject
next
```

Comment: Yes I did mean to sort newest to oldest. I would just change the boolean in the Sort function to True. For the most part, it works like it is supposed to but there are times when it does it the way it is shown in my post. Just trying to figure why that is.

Comment: And in the case when the order is wrong, does the script above exhibit the same wrong behavior?

Comment: What dims are you using? Because when I try to use Msg.Subject to search, it gives me an Run-time error '438' message saying that "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: I made a big mistake. I had the mail in different subfolders and the earliest one was in the subfolder above the folder that the other mail was in. Sorry for causing so much frustration and confusion. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub AdvSearchForStr()

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim rsts As Results
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rstObj As Object
    Dim myMsg As MailItem
    
    strSearch = "Test"

    Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" & strSearch & "%'"
    Debug.Print strFilter

    Dim strScope As String
    'strScope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items', 'Tasks'"
    strScope = "'Inbox'"

    Dim objSearch As Search
    Set objSearch = Application.AdvancedSearch(Scope:=strScope, Filter:=strFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="SearchFolder")

    'Save the search results to a searchfolder
    'objSearch.Save (strSearch)
    
    ' Delay to allow search to complete
    ' The Application.AdvancedSearchComplete event appears to be broken
    '  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearchcomplete
    Dim waitTime As Long
    Dim delay As Date
    
    waitTime = 1    ' in seconds - adjust as needed
    Debug.Print vbCr & "Wait start: " & Now
        
    delay = DateAdd("s", waitTime, Now)
    Debug.Print "Wait until: " & delay
        
    Do Until Now > delay
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set rsts = objSearch.Results
    Debug.Print " rsts.Count: " & rsts.Count
    
    If rsts.Count > 0 Then
        
        rsts.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
        Set rstObj = rsts(1)
        rstObj.Display
        
        Set myMsg = CreateItem(olMailItem)
        myMsg.Attachments.Add rstObj, olEmbeddeditem
        myMsg.Display
    
    Else
    
        Debug.Print "no mail found."
        
    End If

End Sub
```